Unable to perform BulkInsert of records into snowflake tables
public async Task<int> BulkInsertAsync<T>(string tableName, IEnumerable<T> data, int batchSize = 1000)
{
    int totalRowsAffected = 0;
    var batches = data.Batch(batchSize);

    foreach (var batch in batches)
    {
        string connstring = "connection string";
        using SnowflakeDbConnection conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = connstring;
        conn.Open();

        using var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

        try
        {
            var dataTable = batch.ToDataTable();
            var sql = GenerateBulkInsertSql(tableName, dataTable);
            var rowsAffected = await conn.ExecuteAsync(sql, dataTable, transaction: transaction);
            transaction.Commit();
            totalRowsAffected += rowsAffected;
        }
        catch
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }

    return totalRowsAffected;
}

private string GenerateBulkInsertSql(string tableName, DataTable dataTable)
{
    var columns = string.Join(", ", dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName));
    var values = string.Join(", ", dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => ":" + c.ColumnName));
    return $"INSERT INTO {tableName} ({columns}) VALUES ({values})";
}

public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
    }

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        var row = dataTable.NewRow();

        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
        }

        dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return dataTable;
}

Can anyone assist with performing BulkInsert and BulkUpdate operations on Snowflake tables using Dapper and C#? I am encountering issues where the values are not being inserted into the Snowflake tables. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

That's not a bulk insert operation, that's a SQL injection risk that only inserts a single value. Bulk Insert doesn't mean inserting multiple rows with a single call.

Usually, the point of using Dapper is to avoid using DataTable for things; any reason you aren't just passing batch as the parameter?

@PanagiotisKanavos the values are parameterized; I agree it isn't actually a bulk-insert in the true sense, but I see no SQLi here either

Was this AI-generated? This looks like something ChatGPT would generate by misunderstanding how SQL Server's SqlBulkCopy and Dapper work.

@MarcGravell the string interpolation can still cause issues.

@PanagiotisKanavos I don't entirely disagree, but in reality: SQLi based on the property name is not an interesting attack vector - unlike values, it isn't possible to influence the property names as an external caller

What is this code trying to do? From the driver docs I see data files are uploaded into stages and then copied into production tables using COPY INTO. The  PUT example works with a DbDataReader so can be considered equivalent to a SqlBulkCopy operation, just not in a production table

Lose the DataTable. It would be nice if this was hand-written SQL, but it probably isn't a huge problem in this case, but, something along the lines of:
private static string GenerateBulkInsertSql<T>(string tableName)
{
    var propertyNames = typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name);

    var columns = string.Join(", ", propertyNames);
    var values = string.Join(", ", propertyNames.Select(name => ":" + name));
    return $"INSERT INTO {tableName} ({columns}) VALUES ({values})";
}

which should be enough to get you the SQL (the same SQL for every operation), then you should be able to use batch as the parameter value:
    var sql = GenerateBulkInsertSql<T>(tableName);
    foreach (var batch in batches)
    {
        string connstring = "connection string";
        using SnowflakeDbConnection conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = connstring;
        conn.Open();

        using var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

        try
        {
            var rowsAffected = await conn.ExecuteAsync(sql, batch, transaction: transaction);
            transaction.Commit();
            totalRowsAffected += rowsAffected;
        }
        catch
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }


Seems there's an actual "bulk load" command .... PUT. Along with COPY INTO meant to move data from staging to actual tables. The PUT command works with DbDataReader

@PanagiotisKanavos that looks a lot like the TSQL BULK INSERT command, in that it requires a local file rather than a raw data stream, but: please feel free to suggest a better approach in code! My focus here is on simply making the code ... work
